# compatibility of canvas.toBlob() in MSEdge browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge

I am using `canvas.toBlob()` callback method to convert the image file to blob. But I see that `toBlob` is not compatible with microsoft edge browser.

I have tried detecting the browser and based on the browser I am using the `toBlob()`. For Edge we have `canvas.msToBlob()` and for other browsers we have `canvas.toBlob()`. Do we have any common method to create a blob?

```
 let isEdgeBrowser = 
 msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
    if (isEdgeBrowser) {
      let blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    }

   if (!isEdgeBrowser) {
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        this.fileUploadedSize = blob.size;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), we can see that the HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob() method not supported Edge browser, if you want to use this method in Edge browser, try to add the following polyfill:

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
    value: function (callback, type, quality) {
      var dataURL = this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1];
      setTimeout(function() {

        var binStr = atob( dataURL ),
            len = binStr.length,
            arr = new Uint8Array(len);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
          arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );

      });
    }
  });
}
```